# Finding groups in a graph where each element can reach each other

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am writing code to convert a network diagram into a configuration file that can be used to generate a virtual network and I am having trouble determining what nodes are in a vlan.

> vlan: A group of nodes where each node has an edge to every other node in the group. A node can be in several vlans.

For example: Nodes a,b,c have edges that connect to each other and are considered to be a vlan. Nodes c,d,e have edges that connect to each other and are considered to be another vlan.

My first approach was to iterate through a list of all the nodes in the graph. In each iteration, I would follow each edge and see if each edge of the current node was an edge of the connecting node.

```
//If true, node.edges is a vlan
for node in graph
    for edge in node.edges
        for check_edge in node.edges
            if(check_edge != edge && !(check_edge in edge.edges))
                return false
return true
```

This seems like a really terrible idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is find cliques, which is a very [hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). Without any assumptions, the best you can do is exponential time. I recommend looking through the [cliques of a fixed sized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Cliques_of_fixed_size) algorithms list, because it seems to be the best for what you want (maybe). However, given that your algorithm is `O(nk^3)` with n nodes and k edges, there doesn't seem t o be significant improvement. It's important to realize that finding *all* cliques will be an incredibly hard problem to solve quickly.

Comment: The graphs that I will be analyzing will be <250 nodes and <10 edges per node. Is it worth trying to implement a different algorithm with this (relatively) small dataset?

Comment: Honestly, probably not. Perhaps some clever pre-pruning could be worth looking into (for example, eliminating nodes that you know can no longer be part of any other cliques as you check other nodes because you've used/checked all of their edges).